# Auto increment the filed in Python Django model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my model

```
class Department(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    maximum_number_of_employees = models.PositiveIntegerField(MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3))
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to auto-increment the maximum_number_of_employees field upon the creation of the department and the associate of the employee to each department so that I can validate that the maximum_number_of_employees do not exceed the max limit

Answer (score 1):

Override save method like this:

```
class Department(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    maximum_number_of_employees = models.PositiveIntegerField(MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3))
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         count_employee = Department.objects.select_related('employee').count()
         if  count_employee < MAX_LIMIT: 
             self.maximum_number_of_employees = count_employee
             super(Department).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
         else:
             raise ValueError("Limit exceeded!")
```

Comment: TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Department.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Department.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the DepartmentSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

Comment: Debug if control is reaching overidden save method.

Comment: it is but it was throwing an error on the self.maximum_number_of_employees += 1 because maximum_number_of_employees is receiving None and we can not add +=1 to None

Comment: may be there is a problem in my serializer

Comment: Updated a code check.

Comment: @theknight If this fixed your issue do mark answer as accepted. And if you think it will help future readers then you can upvote it thanks :)